# Правильно ли поставлено двоеточие?

Tags: пунктуация

Такое предложение: "Когда спросили: что это за химикаты и почему мы должны распылять их, они нам сказали, что информация закрытая". Правильно ли тут стоит двоеточие?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это предложение с косвенной речью, поэтому двоеточие не ставится, а ставится запятая. Ваше предложение - это сложноподчинённое предложение с четырьмя  придаточными. Однородные придаточные изъяснительные "...,что это за химикаты и почему мы должны распылять их,..." относятся к другому придаточному "Когда спросили,...", которое является главным для этих однородных придаточных:  СПРОСИЛИ (о чём?). Четвёртое придаточное "что информация закрытая"  относится к главному "они нам сказали".

Answer (score 0):

Править надо. Предложение пресыщено придаточными, на слух не воспринимается, какой знак ни ставь.
А по сути - согласен.